# Remove any column with same values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, equals

I need to remove any column in a matrix which has same values in it.  I designed it using a for-loop in MATLAB.  I wanted to know if a better/faster way exists using vectorization.

```
mat = [ 0.56  0.2 1 0 45; 0.566 0.2 4 0 45; 0.52  0.2 6 0 45; 0.56  0.2 6 0 41 ];  
[row col] = size(mat) ;

bitmat = true(1,col) ;
for i = 2:row, tf = (mat(i-1,:) == mat(i,:)) ; bitmat = bitmat & tf ; end
mat(:,bitmat) = [] ;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple one-liner using the functions [DIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html) and [ANY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/any.html):

```
mat = mat(:,any(diff(mat,1)));
```